# How to set page title in OroCrm (Symfony2) with Twig

Tags: symfony, twig, orocrm

I'm a new in OroCRM and Symfony2. I'm trying to code a page that retrieves all record of a table. But I don't know how to change title of this page, it always displays it's url (http://localhost/crm-application/web/app_dev.php/...).
This is my twig file:

```
{#index.html.twig#}
{% extends 'OroUIBundle:actions:index.html.twig' %}
{% import 'OroUIBundle::macros.html.twig' as UI %}

{% set gridName = 'b2b-customers-grid' %}
{% set pageTitle = 'B2B Customers' %}
```

I have tried many way but i could not make it. I usually get that error:

```
A template that extends another one cannot have a body”
```

Any help? Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

pageTitle is not that title that you think of, as I understand you want to set title for the whole page, browser window title, head > title in html, and pageTitle variable it's for content header title.

Do you have any other content in your index.html.twig? That could be the reason you got an error.

To set window title, you should use navigation.yml in your bundle's Resources/config with something like

```
oro_titles:
    orocrm_account_index: ~
```

or

```
oro_titles:
    orocrm_account_index: 'Create Account'
```

Don't forget to clear cache after that, if you had no this file before and run app/console oro:navigation:init to reload titles configuration